# Requests against elmah.axd always fails with a 500 - Internal server error. Why? :-(

Tags: asp.net, elmah, episerver

I used the NuPack tool to add Elmah to a site on my developer machine. This worked like a charm, but when I send a request to the elmah.axd page all I get in return is 500 - Internal server error.

My code setup:
Visual Studio 2010
Site built on top of EPiServer 4.62B
Running on .NET Framework 2 (because of EPiServer)

My IIS setup:
IIS 7.5
Classic .NET AppPool (because of EPiServer)

My computer:
running Windows 7 32bit (because of EPiServer)

ELMAH content in web.config:

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
  <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
</sectionGroup>
```

inside configSections.

```
<elmah>
  <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
  <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
</elmah>
```

At this stage I don't really need allowRemoteAccess since I am running everyting from my machine, but trying anything at the moment. And I know elmah.dll is running because the log files are beeing created.

```
<add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
```

inside system.web | httpHandlers.

```
<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
<add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
<add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
```

inside system.web | httpmodules.

```
<add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
<add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
<add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
```

inside system.webServer | modules

```
<add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
```

inside system.webServer | handlers

I have basically added every suggestion I could find on the net to the web.config, but without it doing any good. Which leads me to believe that something else is wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I've found that works is to switch my application pool to integrated mode. My app hasn't been fully tested against this though, so I haven't change this in production.

Comment: Marking this one as the answer. Beeing stuck in the single threaded pool seems to be the reason elmah wont properly (probably ELMAH works as it should but the single threaded pool can't make proper use of it).

Answer (score 2):

You dont have a connection string to the Elmah database in there.

Also have you added the Elmah and SqlLite dlls to your bin folder?

I have a minimal setup guide here which might help:
http://www.codeulike.com/2010/05/quick-elmah-setup.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! At the moment Elmah is set up to use xml files when tracking errors. So, no connection string needed. And Elmah is producing the files, so the elmah.dll is working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the elmah_error DB table needs repair.

It happened in my case a couple of times and by repairing, it was fixed.

I had the exact same problem elmah-> 500 - Internal Server Error.

just run mysql command:

`repair table elmah.elmah_error;`

and retry to access elmah.

Comment: Just saw this answer now. So bummed I do not have this up and running anymore :) Would be so cool to know it this was the answer all along.